# Symfony runtime exception after assetic:dump

Tags: symfony, assets

```
The source file "C:/Users/John/workspace/Project1/app/../web/.." does not exist
```

the command will process all the files but why the error ?

Done a php app/console assets:install first
Also tried clearing the cache.

Comment: Solved it, my twig implementation was faulty. Appearently an assetic dump scans your twig files too.